# Rails, model with column of integer array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added created new migration:

```
class AddColumnsToDiscipline < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   add_column :disciplines, :days, :integer, array: true
 end
end
```

Then I have run migration.

In my `seed.rb` file I have added this

```
t.disciplines.create(name: Company.name, days: [1, 2, 3])
```

After when I run `rake db:seed`, When I run my `rails console` all created models `days` attribute has `nil` value. Whad did I miss?

Comment: try this with default value and not integer `add_column :disciplines, :days, :text, array: true, default: []`  in your migration file and then run `rake db:seed` command

Comment: what is your database?.

Answer (score 7):

try this with `default` option

```
add_column :disciplines, :days, :integer, array: true, default: []
```

in your migration file and then

```
run rake db:seed
```

**EDIT**

Try as

```
add_column :disciplines, :days, :integer, array: true, default: '{}'
```

and change `create` to `create!`

```
t.disciplines.create!(name: Company.name, days: [1, 2, 3])
```

If you are using `strong parameters` have you permitted `days` in your controller

Comment: I have added `default: []` and remigrated my database. Then run seed, still gives me `nil`

Comment: @Mr.D Try as `add_column :disciplines, :days, :integer, array: true, default: '{}'`

Comment: I have tried this changed `[]` to `'{}'`. Still the same

Comment: @Mr.D - are you using strong parameters?

Comment: I'm Using rails 4. That means yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75197/discussion-between-sontya-and-mr-d).

Comment: I have opened chat, where are you?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was opened in rails public repo. follow [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10432#issuecomment-21029629).

`rails 4-0-stable` have come with that fix. Maybe you need to update the rails version :D.

Comment: I have rails 4.1 version

Comment: oops. may other can help you now.